# Reducing Load On Server

Tags: linux, email, load

I am having the strangest of issues with a cPanel server.
Basically the server is using very little CPU and Memory in comparisson to what it has available but still the server's load keeps driving up to 10-30 /8 throughout the day.

This is causing website's loading times to become worse and email delivery to become slower.

This only started happening when we started running mailscanner on the server to stop spam from coming in.

The server currently processes between 35000-50000 emails per day of which about 11% is spam.
Mailscanner is set to have 10 children (any less and the mail queue heaps up as processing is slower than mails coming in).
There are just under 500 accounts on the server most of which only have basic websites and we are running cloud linux on the server...

What can I do to increase the performance, or find what is causing the load?

Please see the statistics below for the load running at 16/8

```
top - 11:32:03 up 3 days, 22:27,  2 users,  load average: 16.83, 14.68, 11.86
Tasks: 591 total,   2 running, 588 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s): 17.8%us,  8.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 48.6%id, 23.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  2.2%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  32753316k total, 32226432k used,   526884k free,  3335088k buffers
Swap: 12581880k total,    98944k used, 12482936k free, 21865996k cached
```